# Reading GLTF vertex color encoding

Tags: gltf

I'm trying to parse the BoxVertexColors GLTF 2.0 file from the official test sample set and store the information in my own data structures. I've got the position, normals, etc to work, but the result parsing the vertex color mesh attribute is weird.

The .gltf states the format is 5126 (=float) and VEC4, the starting offset is 0x288. When looking into the buffer.bin file, the content at 0x288 starts with

```
1D E9 06 30   7A 7A 25 3C   FE FF 7F 3F   51 D2 27 30
```

which doesn't look like floats to me, let alone an encoded color. I would have expected four floats representing RGBA. What am I missing ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think the data is incorrect?

```
  (0x3006E91D, 0X3C257A7A, 0x3F7FFFFE, 0x3727D251) =>
  (4.90802e-10, 0.0101, 1.0, 6.10531e-10) => (simplified)
  (0, 0.0101, 1.0, 0)
```

Apart from the possibly nonsensical alpha value, this seems like a perfectly reasonable start position for what's clearly a computed range of colours spread across a cube.

The alpha value is ultimately irrelevant, because the associated material does not specify a blendMode setting, which in turn means it defaults to OPAQUE, and thus transparency is ignored.

Loading the model in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ and breakpointing confirms that the data is decoded as you'd expect:

[image: JavaScript Debugger]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The alpha value indeed made me think I MUST have gotten something wrong! : )

Comment: The alpha values are partially my fault.  The original model had vertex color transparency as well, but using it disabled z-buffering in most standard WebGL-based renderers, making the model visually incoherent.  So I lazily removed `alphaMode: BLEND` and as a result the alpha values are completely ignored, and z-buffering is enabled.  Someday we should get a model that makes better use of vertex-color alpha.

Comment: Well, I guess we can see it from a positive side: if you wouldn't have done it this way, I never would have found this use case and probably wouldn't have implemented it correctly. I had noticed that my code wasn't probably handling the AlphaBlendModeTest sample but since I'm writing an importer for my 3D geometry processing application, rendering is not the primary concern and I - incorrectly - thought I could ignore that topic for a while longer...